# installing and configuring Globus toolkit 6.0 on my machine running Fedora 20

Tags: grid, globus-toolkit

I am trying to setup a grid using Globus Toolkit 6.0 on my Fedora 20 machine. Steps given in Globus's website found to be pretty confusing. 
I've installed repositories through .rpm file of gt6(downloaded from toolkit.globus.org). Then I followed steps given in that website. I configured security certificates using SimpleCA. 
However while initiating proxy i got some error. 
If anyone have solution of this problem, then please suggest,
Or if you've any alternative steps to install and configure Globus Toolkit 6.0 on fedora 20 please suggest...!

Comment: What was the error? What steps did you follow exactly? You state that you were confused by the installation guide.

Comment: I've used steps given on "http://toolkit.globus.org/toolkit/docs/6.0/admin/install/#install-bininst", which is official website of Globus.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx, 
I solved my problem.
Error was regarding with certificate creation and signing it...